# How to get same NumberGroupSeparator on different system?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am executing below code on two different system for German(Switzerland) "de-CH" locale and I am getting different number group separator on both system.

```
  var nfi = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-CH").NumberFormat;
  var separator = nfi.NumberGroupSeparator;
  Console.WriteLine(separator);
```

- Windows 10: **’**
- Windows Server 2016: **'**

**Note:** I am using .NET Framework **4.6.2**

Comment: I want to know why you want to get same the same Separator.

Comment: I have requirement like this.

1. I am getting data from server suppose 123'456.7895 
    (locale - "de-CH", OS - Windows Server 2016)
2. Now, I have one windows application which is running on client system and I need to validate the above data 123'456.7895 with given locale.
(locale - "de-CH", OS - Windows 10)

Actual separator on Windows 10 : ’
Expected separator on Windows 10 : ' (same as  Windows Server 2016)

Comment: Since I am using CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-CH") and as per MSDN it will not honor user formatting so, I am expecting same format on both (client and server system)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to change the default NumberGroupSeparator.

```
      var valueNumber = "123'456.7898";
        var nfi = new CultureInfo("de-CH", false).NumberFormat;
        nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "'";
        bool t = double.TryParse(valueNumber, NumberStyles.Number, nfi, out double result);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code @Jack but I am getting formatted data from server and I need to validate that formatted data on client system.

Comment: How do you get the formatted data? How do you want to verify the formatted data?

Comment: Code executing on server which gives formatted data.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
            var valueNumber = "123,456.7898";
            double.TryParse(valueNumber, NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo("en-US", false), out double result);
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-CH", false);
            var numberFormatInfo = cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
            numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits = 4;
            var swissFormat = result.ToString("N", numberFormatInfo);
            Console.WriteLine(swissFormat);

Comment: Code executing on client system which is validating the above data
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            var valueNumber = "123'456.7898";
            var nfi = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-CH").NumberFormat;
            double.TryParse(valueNumber, NumberStyles.Number, nfi, out double result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: What is your client result? I get '0'.

Comment: Yeah true, I am not able to validate it and this is because Windows 10 gives ’ group separator instead of '

Comment: I assume if we use below it should give same group separator on both system, but it is not.

  var nfi = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-CH").NumberFormat;
  var separator = nfi.NumberGroupSeparator;
  Console.WriteLine(separator);

Comment: Why not write the numbergroupseparator directly instead of getting it so hard?

Comment: in our application we have implemented localization, so it won't be a good idea to write numbergroupseparator explicitly. We are having issues with couple of locales only (de-CH, fr-CH) rest are working fine.